# Select unique record from two tables when column count is not same in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, both tables has same column but one table has extra columns. I need to select unique record from both of them on the basis of a column i.e. profilelink in below example exists in both table.

I tried union in below way:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t2
```

but I think it is check for all columns in the table and then fetch out the result but in my case column count is not same in both tables and I need to fetch record on the basis of one column only. So can someone help me in this query.

Table structure is as follows

Table 1

```
id  |   name    |   marks   |   profilelink
1   |   a       |   10      |   http://example.com/a
2   |   b       |   20      |   http://example.com/b
3   |   c       |   30      |   http://example.com/c
4   |   d       |   40      |   http://example.com/d
```

Table 2

```
id  |   name    |   marks   |   Division    |   Result  |   profilelink
1   |   e       |   10      |   I           |   Pass    |   http://example.com/e
2   |   f       |   20      |   II          |   Pass    |   http://example.com/f
3   |   b       |   30      |   III         |   Pass    |   http://example.com/b
4   |   c       |   40      |   IV          |   Fail    |   http://example.com/c
```

Expected Result would be

```
id  |   name    |   marks   |   Division    |   Result  |   profilelink
1   |   a       |   10      |   null        |   null    |   http://example.com/a
2   |   d       |   40      |   null        |   null    |   http://example.com/a
3   |   e       |   10      |   I           |   Pass    |   http://example.com/e
4   |   f       |   20      |   II          |   Fail    |   http://example.com/f
```

In the above example profilelink is common in both tables. Result sequence doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you add structure of tables and expected output?

Comment: what do you mean by column count ??

Comment: A great rule-of-thumb is "NEVER use `SELECT *` "

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank You for this, but here I just written example of my approach.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: I have added table structure and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can select the specific columns names of each table but with the same order, like this:

```
SELECT t1_id AS id
     , t1_name AS name 
  FROM t1 
 UNION 
SELECT t2_id 
     , t2_name 
  FROM t2
```

Answer (score 0):

As you told in question, you want to get records from both table which are not duplicate. Below query may help you out.

```
SELECT id, name, marks, profilelink, count(id) as count FROM 
    (SELECT id, name, marks, profilelink 
            from table1 
    UNION 
        SELECT id, name, marks, profilelink from table2) A 
GROUP BY profilelink where count = 1
```

Subquery will get records from both tables and count records based on `profileurl`.

Answer (score 0):

i had try and get all column as result with this Query :

```
 SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`
      FROM table_b 
     UNION 
 SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`,'' as 'Division','' as 'Result', `profilelink`
      FROM table_a
```

Output & Example  :
[image]

Comment: Thanks Gautam, but union should be based on profilelink column only. Not for all.

Comment: Please Try This Query:

select `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink` from (
Select  `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`,  count(id) as count from (
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`
  FROM table_b 
 UNION 
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`,null as 'Division',null as 'Result', `profilelink`
  FROM table_a )tbl  group by name )  tbl_Val where  count=1  ;

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Query :

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink` from (
SELECT `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`,  count(id) as count from (
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`
  FROM table_b 
 UNION 
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`,null as 'Division',null as 'Result', `profilelink`
  FROM table_a )tbl  group by name )  tbl_Val where  count=1  ;
```

Comment: I think we need to use profilelink column to compare in both tables because in both tables only profilelink column can identified for duplicacy. Am I right?

Comment: Ok Boss its just an idea to get Results please you may proceed as you want.

Comment: SELECT `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink` from (
SELECT `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`,  count(id) as count from (
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`, `Division`, `Result`, `profilelink`
  FROM table_b 
 UNION 
SELECT  `id`, `name`, `marks`,null as 'Division',null as 'Result', `profilelink`
  FROM table_a )tbl  group by profilelink )  tbl_Val where  count=1  ;